# Slack Oauth - how do I force my slack app to receive messages in a certain channel?

Tags: oauth-2.0, slack, slack-api

I'm building a Slack app and when I install the app in my workspace, during the Oauth flow it asks me what channel I want messages sent to. I then have to choose among all my channels in a select menu (one of which is my slack app) where to receive messages.

When I install something like the Jira Cloud Slack app, it does not ask me what channel I want to use to receive messages, it just installs the app and I receive messages in the Jira Cloud channel. I'd like to try to set up my slack app so the user does not have to select a channel, but instead the messages go automatically to the app channel (like Jira).

Does anyone know what settings (Oauth scopes maybe?) I need to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Slack's [incoming webhooks](https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks)? Webhooks will require you to specify a channel, but using [Sign in with Slack](https://api.slack.com/docs/sign-in-with-slack) for auth (or just authenticating with their OAuth v2) does not. Also make sure that you're using Slack's most recent version of apps that include granular scopes -- not sure if the legacy apps work like this.

Comment: I'm using webhooks, and messages are sent to users in the channel they select when the app is first installed. 

I'm also using Sign in with Slack as well as an OAuth2 flow for authenticating users. I have a slash command that returns a login link that the user can click on to start the OAuth flow (so I know the channel id). I just can't figure out how to default to that channel for receiving messages when the user first installs and "Allow"s the app to send them messages. I have a feeling it's tied up in the scopes but can't figure out what I need to set for scopes to make this happen.

Comment: I don't think you need to use webhooks at all here. You can send messages to users via the [chat.postMessage method](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage), just give your bot the `chat.write` scope and pass the auth token and user's ID as the destination channel. Your auth link won't have a channel dropdown once you disable incoming webhooks, you'll handle that logic manually to build your request to the postMessage API endpoint.

Comment: The solution: I was asking for "incoming-webhooks" bot scope in my OAuth flow, which requires the user to specify a channel to receive them. I didn't need that scope it turns out, so I removed that from my Oauth scopes and now when a user installs the app, the user is not asked to choose a channel.